# Eclipse RCP. Add an additional condition for view restorable

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

How to add an additional condition for restorable view?
My plugin.xml:

```
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
  <view
        allowMultiple="false"
        class="com.example.ui.example.views.newView"
        icon="icons/example.png"
        id="com.example.ui.example.views.newView"
        name="New View"
        restorable="true">
  </view>
```

I want to view restorable work only on Mondays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restorable is either true or false, there is no support for anything else.

You might be able to use the `org.eclipse.ui.startup` extension point to run code during the Eclipse startup and use `IWorkbenchPage` `showView` / `hideView` to show or hide the view.